# Solve the equation $z^3=z+\overline{z}$

Tags: complex-numbers

I have been trying to solve an equation $z^3=z+\overline{z}$, where $\overline{z}=a-bi$ if $z=a+bi$. But I cant find any clues on how to move forward on that one. Please help.

Comment: Whenever I'm clueless, I split the real part and the imaginary part.

Comment: Whenever I'm clueless, I use the Internet http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=z%5E3%3Dz%2Bconjugate%28z%29 and see if I can figure out myself how to get to that solution.

Comment: Can someone tell me what the bar over the z means?

Comment: @joejacobz : It is the conjugate. The conjugate of a complex number $a+bi$ will be $a-bi$.

Comment: Ok, thanks @SujaanKunalan

Answer (score 15):

Writing out real and imaginary parts of $z$ and separating real and imaginary parts yields
$$
x^3+3ix^2y-3xy^2-iy^3=2x
$$
therefore,
$$
x^3-3xy^2=2x\implies x=0\quad\text{or}\quad x^2-3y^2=2
$$
and
$$
3x^2y-y^3=0\implies y=0\quad\text{or}\quad3x^2=y^2
$$
If $y=0$, then $x^3=2x\implies x\in\{0,\sqrt2,-\sqrt2\}$.

If $x=0$, then $y=0$.

If $x^2-3y^2=2$ and $3x^2=y^2$, then $-8x^2=2$.

Thus, $(x,y)\in\{(0,0),(\sqrt2,0),(-\sqrt2,0)\}$; that is, $z\in\{0,\sqrt2,-\sqrt2\}$.

Comment: would the downvoter care to comment?

Comment: @Downvoter: what did you do without any comments or any signs was Nothing. (+1)

Answer (score 6):

You have that $z^3$ is real, since it equals $z+\bar{z}$. So $z$ is on one of six regularly spaced rays pointing from the origin. In four cases out of six, $z^3$ and $z+\bar{z}$ would have opposing real parts and thus cannot be equal. This only leaves the two rays where $z$ itself is real. And your equation is reduced to $$z^3=2z\implies z(z-\sqrt{2})(z+\sqrt{2})=0$$

Answer (score 5):

Note that if $z=a+ib$ then $z+\overline{z}=2a$ and
$$
z^3=2a
$$
The cube roots of $2a$ are

\begin{align}
\sqrt[3]{2a}\cdot\omega^{0}
=
&
\sqrt[3]{2a}
\\
\sqrt[3]{2a}\cdot\omega^{1}
=
&
\sqrt[3]{2a}\big(\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\big)
\\
\sqrt[3]{2a}\cdot\omega^{2}
=
&
\sqrt[3]{2a}\big(\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\big)^{2}=\sqrt[3]{2a}\big(\frac{1}{2}-i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\big)
\end{align}
where $\omega=\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt[3]{3}}{2}$ is any cubic root of the unit.The possible values ​​of $ a $ and $ b $ are obtained equaling $ z = a + ib$ to the roots of  given above $2a$.
\begin{align}
\sqrt[3]{2a}\cdot\omega^{0}
=
&
\sqrt[3]{2a}
\\
\sqrt[3]{2a}\cdot\omega^{1}
=
&
\sqrt[3]{2a}\big(\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\big)^{1}
\\
\sqrt[3]{2a}\cdot\omega^{2}
=
&
\sqrt[3]{2a}\big(\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\big)^{2}=\sqrt[3]{2a}\big(\frac{1}{2}-i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\big)
\end{align}
More explicitly
\begin{align}
a+ib
=
&
\sqrt[3]{2a}
\\
a+ib
=
&
\frac{1}{2}\sqrt[3]{2a}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sqrt[3]{2a}
\\
a+ib
=
&
\frac{1}{2}\sqrt[3]{2a}-i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sqrt[3]{2a}
\end{align}

Comment: It should be $a^3-3ab^2$ and $3a^2b-b^3$

Comment: Um, doesn't $\omega=\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$

Comment: I’m sorry to downvote, but the cube roots of unity are not correctly given, and a glance at the case $z\in\mathbb R$ shows that $0,\pm\sqrt2$ are roots. And this answer doesn’t give a nod in that direction.

Comment: This answer changed quite a lot from its first incarnation, where Ross Millikan's comment was relevant.

Comment: @Lubin ok. Sorry I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 5):

You have $(a+bi)^3=2a$ Now expand the cube and equate real and imaginary parts

Answer (score 4):

$$z^3=z+\bar{z}=2\,{\rm Re}(z)\implies z^3\in{\bf R}\implies z=\omega r ~~(\omega^3=1,r\in{\bf R})$$

$$r^3=(\omega+\overline{\omega})r\implies\begin{cases} r=0 \\ r^2=2\,{\rm Re}(\omega) \implies\begin{cases} r=\pm\sqrt{2} & \omega=1 \\ r^2<0 & \omega\ne1\end{cases}\end{cases} $$

Thus the solutions are $0$ and $\pm\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Honor the departed. +1

Comment: Very nice! $\left . \right .$

Answer (score 1):

Conjugating you get
$$\bar{z}^3=\bar{z}+z,$$
so
$$z^3=\bar{z}^3.$$ Now use the initial equation to substitute $\bar{z}$, after some algebra you get
$$\begin{align*}
z^3 &= \left( z^3-z \right)^3 \\
0   &= z^3- \left( z^3-z \right)^3\\
    &= z^3\left( 2-z^2 \right)\left( z+i\left( z^2-1 \right) \right)\left( z- i\left( z^2-1 \right) \right).
\end{align*}$$

Now you have to solve two quadratic equations which you know how to.

**Edit.** As pointed in the comments you have to to keep only the real solutions because $z+\bar{z}=2\Re(z)$.

Comment: It is true that if $z$ satisfies $z^3=z+\bar{z}$ it must also be a zero of the polynomial you have at the end. However, the converse is false: there are zeros of the polynomial at the end that are not solutions to the equation $z^3=z+\bar{z}$ (namely, the complex solutions). See "[extraneous solutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraneous_and_missing_solutions)."

Comment: @anon thanks, you are right. I guess that the not reversible transformation made to that equation is the substitution step.

Answer (score 1):

This is akin particularly to the methods described by **Elias** , **Sujaan Kunalan** and **nbubis** :

The sum of a complex number and its conjugate produce a pure real number,

$$ z \ + \ \overline{z} \ = \ 2a \ = \ 2a \ \cdot \ cis (0) = \ 2a \ \cdot \ cis (2 \pi)  \ , $$

$ \ cis( \theta ) \ $ being the abbreivated form of $ \ \cos \theta \ + \ i \sin \theta \ \ . $  DeMoivre's Theorem then gives us

$$ z^3 \ = \ r^3  \cdot \ cis(3 \theta) \ = \ 2a \ \cdot \ cis (2 \pi) , $$

with $ \ r \ $ being the modulus of $ \ z \ $ and $ \ \theta \ $ its argument.  We thus obtain  $ \ r^3 = 2a \ $  and the "trigonometric" equation  $ \ cis(3 \theta) \ = \ cis (2 \pi) , $

which is solved (within the "principal circle", $ \ 0 \ \le \ \theta \ < \ 2 \pi \ $ ) by  $ \ \theta \ = \ \frac{0 + 2k \pi}{3} \ , \ \text{for} \ k = 0,1,2 , $

which is described by what is also called DeMoivre's Theorem for roots.

**EDIT:**  Oops, need to take this a bit further.

So there are three apparent solutions,

$$z \ = \ (2a)^{1/3} \ , \ (2a)^{1/3} \cdot cis(\frac{2\pi}{3}) \ , \ \text{and} \ (2a)^{1/3} \cdot cis(\frac{4\pi}{3}) \ . $$

For all three, however, we have $ \ z \ + \ \overline{z} \ = \ 2 \cdot (2a)^{1/3} \ , $ which must also equal $ \ 2a \ , $ which is real.   Hence, $ \ (2a)^{1/3} \ = \ a \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ a^{1/3} \ \cdot \ (a^{2/3} - 2^{1/3}) = 0 \ ,  $ which is solved by $ \ a = 0 \ , \ \sqrt{2} \ , \ \text{and} \ -\sqrt{2} \ , $
as found by other posters.  So there are three solutions are pure *real* numbers.

**FURTHER EDIT:**  Hmmm, not quite done, on thinking about this a little more.  We've established moduli for solutions, but we should also look at the results for   $ \ (2a)^{1/3} \cdot cis(\frac{2\pi}{3}) \ , \ \text{and} \ (2a)^{1/3} \cdot cis(\frac{4\pi}{3}) \ . $

For $ \ a = \sqrt{2} \ , \ z \ =  \ \sqrt{2} \cdot cis(\frac{2\pi}{3}) \  \ \text{and} \ \sqrt{2} \cdot cis(\frac{4\pi}{3}) \ $, with $ \ \overline{z} \ =  \ \sqrt{2} \cdot cis(\frac{4\pi}{3}) \  \ \text{and} \ \sqrt{2} \cdot cis(\frac{2\pi}{3}) \ , $ respectively, so
$ \ z + \overline{z} \ = \ -2 \sqrt{2} \  , $    but $ \ z^3 \ = \ ( \sqrt{2})^3 \ \cdot \ cis(3 \ \cdot \frac{2 \pi}{3}) \ =  \ 2 \sqrt{2} \ , \ $ and likewise for the argument $ \frac{4 \pi}{3} \ . $

The same thing happens for $ \ a = -\sqrt{2} \ , $  since we have $ \ z \ =  \ -\sqrt{2} \cdot cis(\frac{2\pi}{3}) \ =  \ \sqrt{2} \cdot cis(\frac{5\pi}{3}) \ ,  $ for which $ \ \overline{z} \ =  \ \sqrt{2} \cdot cis(\frac{\pi}{3}) \  $   so,
$ \ z + \overline{z} \ = \ 2 \sqrt{2} \  \   , $ while

$$z^3 \ = \ ( -\sqrt{2})^3 \ \cdot \ cis(3 \ \cdot \frac{2 \pi}{3}) \ = \ (-2 \sqrt{2}) \cdot cis(2 \pi) \ = \ (-2 \sqrt{2}) \cdot (+1) \ = \ -2 \sqrt{2} \ , $$

and similarly for   $ \ z \ =  \ -\sqrt{2} \cdot cis(\frac{4\pi}{3}) \ =  \ \sqrt{2} \cdot cis(\frac{\pi}{3}) \ .  $

So it would seem that all of the complex values really are extraneous (as **alex.jordan** points out).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $z^3=z+\overline{z} \implies z^3=a+bi+a-bi=2a$

Answer (score 0):

One more way to think about it would be in polar coordinates:
$$z+z^*=re^{i\theta}+re^{-i\theta}= 2r\cos(\theta)=r^3 e^{3i\theta}$$
One obvious solution is $z=r=0$. If $r>0$, then since $e^{3i\theta}$ must be real, $\theta =n\pi/3$, which gives six  values for $\theta$, but not all are really possible. For instance, $\theta=\pi/3$ gives:
$$r=-r^3$$
Ultimately, only $\theta = 0,\pi$ are solutions for $r>0$, so that:
$$2r=r^3 \ \to \ z= \pm \sqrt{2}$$